# Which EC2 instance size should I use if I have 100 concurrent users daily and 300 max users? I need to save cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-devops

I have made a Business Card ordering portal and its backend is in NodeJS.

I am currently using t2.micro and I am getting like 50 daily users and 15-20 concurrent users but in some time the user count would go up to 300 daily users and 100 concurrent users. I don't want to spend much either.

It has single database and we don't use threads.

I am confused whether I should change my instance type or should use Auto Scaling Groups.

I am not a pro in AWS. Please help!!

Comment: Load test your app.

Comment: Which way to go is depending on multiple factors (how was the code written, do you use threads, single database, etc. etc.) and we can't answer that question. Like jarmod mentioned, just load test the application.

Comment: I will do the load testing. and its a single database  and we don't use threads. I need to manage like 100 concurrent users. which will be the best instance for that? I thought it would be simple question for experts

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can give you an answer to your question because every application is different.

Some applications need more CPU (eg for encoding/encrypting). Some need lots of RAM (for calculations). Some need lots of disk access (eg for file manipulation).

Only *you* know how your application behaves and what resources it would need.

You could either pick something and then monitor it (CPU, RAM, Disk) in production to see where the 'bottleneck' lies, or you could create a test that simulates the load of users and pushes it to breaking point to discover the bottleneck.